# How to prevent RefreshIndicator from triggering ScrollStartNotification

Tags: flutter, dart

How to prevent the function _onStartScroll from running when refresh indicator is active? Try swiping down to activate refresh, you should the word 'bottom' in the console.

```
class TempScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: NotificationListener(
          onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
            if (scrollNotification is ScrollStartNotification) {
              _onStartScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
            }
          },
          child: RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: () {

              return Future.delayed(
                  Duration(
                    milliseconds: 700,
                  ),
                      () => null);
            },
            child: CustomScrollView(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Swipe Down"),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }

  _onStartScroll(ScrollMetrics metrics) {
    if (metrics.pixels == metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
      print('bottom');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when refresh indicator is active"?

Comment: when [onRefresh()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator/onRefresh.html) callback gets invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can only learn scroll direction on update, so we'll listen only for first update after drag start:

```dart
bool isStarted = false;

...
      onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
        if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
          if (!isStarted) {
            isStarted = true;

            if (scrollNotification.metrics.pixels - scrollNotification.dragDetails.delta.dy > 0) {
              _onStartScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
            }
          }
        } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
          isStarted = false;
        }
      },
```

Comment: @JamieWhite Could you, please, describe the problem more precisely?

Comment: How do I stop _onStartScroll() from running when I swipe down for RefreshIndicator?

Comment: You have this the opposite way around - _onStartScroll needs to run when onNotification() indicates scroll has started. It should NOT run when RefreshIndicator is running.

Comment: @JamieWhite Change the condition to >? I edited the answer.

Comment: Still does not print 'bottom' - on swipe up _onStartScroll needs to output the word 'bottom' (because scroll has reached bottom), on swipe down _onStartScroll should not run.

Comment: @JamieWhite Try `metrics.pixels >= metrics.maxScrollExtent` condition in _onStartScroll.

Comment: Anyway to achieve this without using a flag? I need a solution without variables. I'm trying to refactor all the classes, make them stateless widgets without any variables inside them - using blocs to manage data.

Comment: @JamieWhite Sorry, I don't have an idea right now. So did it work for you?